# Can you install Deja-dup on a headless server?

Tags: server, backup, restore, deja-dup, headless

Can I install a command line version of deja-dup backup utility on Ubuntu server?

I wish to restore a backup of my previous Home directory made with deja-dup.

Comment: what about the scheduled tasks? I installed and configured it on a vnc session on the server. I scheduled the backup weekly, but there is no backup since 10 days. Is there something i have to activate? THX

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't.  But Deja Dup is just a graphical front end for the command line tool duplicity, which you *can* use on a server.

Its command line interface is a bit complicated, but read its man page or some of the instructions in Deja Dup's manual restore help page: https://live.gnome.org/DejaDup/Help/Restore/WorstCase

Comment: Can you please write instructions to an specific use-case as an example ?   @Michael Terry

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can. I just did.

Follow [the instructions here](http://nixcraft.com/getting-started-tutorials/170-run-remote-x-applications-over-network-using-ssh.html) and you can run deja-dup using the X of your own machine.

Then you just execute from your local machine:

```
ssh -X SERVER_IP deja-dup
```

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: Does the automatic scheduling work?

Comment: This was basically my plan, and I ran into a problem (which is why I'm googling around...).  Basically, if I want to add a Google drive (or other cloud storage location), Deja-Dup tries to run gnome-control-center (I think), which doesn't work on Ubuntu Server (as far as I have gotten, anyway).  Just a heads up to anybody going down this path.

Comment: @Fabby Time to buy a lottery ticket, looks like you can see the future! The aforementioned link has rotted.